# How to check bluetooth profiles supported by other BLE devices?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-lowenergy-4.2

1. I want to check BLE profiles supported by slave devices in Bluedroid.
2. Is there any tools/apps to do that?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check BLE profiles supported by slave devices in Bluedroid.

Bluedroid itself, does not support BLE profiles actually but only expose GATT interfaces to upper layer, well at core spec it said GATT is also a profile, but we need write apps over it. This app implemented the BLE profile, e.g. heart rate. and BLE profile included service/characteristic/descriptor.

> Is there any tools/apps to do that?

One app, named "LightBlue" on iOS can help you to find out remote device which profile it supported.

Answer (score 0):

The Service Discovery Protocol (see [here](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=286439) pag. 1907) is used to discover services on a remote device and for each service you can see the list of profiles to which the service conforms. You can use [`sdptool`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sdptool) from BlueZ to read the list of supported services:

e.g., `sdptool browse 00:80:98:24:15:6D`

Comment: Hi ricc, Thanks for reply.  For Android Marshmallow, Bluedroid stack , you know any tool like sdptool for Android.

Comment: How we can find out profiles supported by single-mode devices(BLE) in android?